# How does one implicitly compile a C++ executable using GNU-Make?

Tags: c++, makefile

I have an implicit gnu-makefile side by side with my Cross-platform build file so that I can debug either with the other.

I am trying to keep my architecture constrained such that my builds are implicit in gnu make. This will help restrict any wild build patterns.

I have managed to make everything implicit except for the executable. My makefile is:

```
CXX=c++
CXXFLAGS+=-std=c++17

CXXFLAGS+=$(shell pkg-config --cflags tesseract)
LDFLAGS+=$(shell pkg-config --libs tesseract)

CXXFLAGS+=$(shell pkg-config --cflags lept)
LDFLAGS+=$(shell pkg-config --libs lept)


main: main.o
ocr-memtest: ocr-memtest.o
```

However, the last implicit step (the executable) is not linking the standard library (my guess):

```
in ocr-memtest.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      _main in ocr-memtest.o
  "operator delete[](void*)", referenced from:
      _main in ocr-memtest.o
  "operator delete(void*)", referenced from:
      _main in ocr-memtest.o
  "operator new(unsigned long)", referenced from:
      _main in ocr-memtest.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      _main in ocr-memtest.o
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in ocr-memtest.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [ocr-memtest] Error 1
```

---

With a virtually identical makefile:

```
CXX=c++
CXXFLAGS+=-std=c++17

CXXFLAGS+=$(shell pkg-config --cflags tesseract)
LDFLAGS+=$(shell pkg-config --libs tesseract)

CXXFLAGS+=$(shell pkg-config --cflags lept)
LDFLAGS+=$(shell pkg-config --libs lept)


main: main.o
ocr-memtest: ocr-memtest.o
  $(CXX) -o $@ $< $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) # only change
```

**I am able to compile and run the same code successfully.**

---

The respective compiler output for the two methods on this mac with brew installed packages is:

```
#implicit, non-working
c++ -std=c++17 -I/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/5.0.1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/leptonica/1.82.0/include/leptonica -I/usr/local/Cellar/leptonica/1.82.0/include/leptonica   -c -o ocr-memtest.o ocr-memtest.cpp
cc -L/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/5.0.1/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/libarchive/3.5.2/lib -ltesseract -larchive -lcurl -L/usr/local/Cellar/leptonica/1.82.0/lib -llept  ocr-memtest.o   -o ocr-memtest
```

```
# manual, working
c++ -std=c++17 -I/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/5.0.1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/leptonica/1.82.0/include/leptonica -I/usr/local/Cellar/leptonica/1.82.0/include/leptonica   -c -o ocr-memtest.o ocr-memtest.cpp
c++ -o ocr-memtest ocr-memtest.o -std=c++17 -I/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/5.0.1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/leptonica/1.82.0/include/leptonica -I/usr/local/Cellar/leptonica/1.82.0/include/leptonica -L/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/5.0.1/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/libarchive/3.5.2/lib -ltesseract -larchive -lcurl -L/usr/local/Cellar/leptonica/1.82.0/lib -llept
```

---

I suspect **I have some misunderstanding** that has resulted in me doing something subtly different than expected... How would I configure this make to render the code implicitly all the way to the executable?

Comment: It probably links the object files using `gcc` instead of `g++` or `c++`. Not sure how to persuade it to use the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way a recipe that only knows the executable name and object file prerequisites can guess what compiler front-end should be used to link: C, C++, Fortran, whatever.

You can find the implicit rules via:

```
make -f/dev/null -p
```

You'll see that an executable uses this built-in rule:

```
%: %.o
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
        $(LINK.o) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

Then if you look for `LINK.o` you'll see:

```
# default
LINK.o = $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)
```

So, the default recipe uses `CC`.

You can either use:

```
CC = $(CXX)
```

Or you can redefine `LINK.o`:

```
LINK.o = $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)
```

Comment: @Chris, from the details of the pattern rule, you should also be able to see that `LDFLAGS` is the wrong variable to use to specify libraries to link to the executable.  Its contents appear too early in the link command.  `LDLIBS` (my personal preference) or `LOADLIBES` are what they should be using for the purpose.

Comment: Good catch John; I should have noticed that myself.